# Pop to top of Navigation View Controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to set up a Navigation View where a user can enter in settings.  Once a setting is finalized in the 3rd level (after a button press outside of the navigation bar), I would like to have the Navigation View popped back to the root.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[UINavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:animated];`, where `animated` is a BOOL.