# How to remove all views from navigation stack?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have around 25 views in a navigation based app. From the 25th view I want to come back to home screen. How do I remove all the views from navigation stack? Do I have to check for each view is not nil and remove from stack?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pop to top of Navigation View Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631787/pop-to-top-of-navigation-view-controller)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use popToRootViewController using this method: `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`
Refer: [popToRootViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)